# Indent all tags in vim HTML

Tags: html, xml, vim

I have noticed in vim's HTML mode that it only indents the tags that are noted as being core HTML tags, like body, li, p, etc.

In doing this, it ignores anything not seen as an HTML tag, such as web components and Angular directives. Is there anyway for vim to indent all tags in HTML regardless of whether they are an HTML-specific tag (basically treat HTML like XML)?

Comment: You can do `:setf xml|%=|setf html`.

Comment: Just tried this, it didn't seem to do anything to the indentation.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a great answer, but you can

```
:setf xml
gg=G
:setf html
```